# What does actually doing isBaselineRelativeArrangement property in UIStackView alignment process?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Apple docs says:

> If YES, the vertical space between views are measured from the last
> baseline of a text-based view, to the first baseline of the view below
> it. Top and bottom views are also positioned so that their closest
> baseline is the specified distance away from the stack view’s edge.
> This property is only used by vertical stack views. Use the alignment
> property to baseline align views in a horizontal stack view.

I tried to see that in code. I created simple stackView consisting of 3 UIViews. In each UIView there's a UITextView with dummy text.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let saveButton = UIView()
    saveButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    saveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let saveButtonTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 50))
    saveButtonTextView.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
    saveButtonTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    saveButton.addSubview(saveButtonTextView)
    
    
    let revertButton = UIView()
    revertButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    revertButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let revertButtonTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 50))
    revertButtonTextView.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
    revertButtonTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    revertButton.addSubview(revertButtonTextView)
    
    let cancelButton = UIView()
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cancelButtonRevertView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 50))
    cancelButtonRevertView.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
    cancelButtonRevertView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cancelButton.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView)
    
    let views = [saveButton,revertButton,cancelButton]
    
    saveButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    revertButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    cancelButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    
    // give the stack view arranged subviews
    let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: views)
    // configure the stack view
    sv.axis = .vertical
    sv.alignment = .fill
    sv.distribution = .equalSpacing
    // constrain the stack view
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.isBaselineRelativeArrangement = true
    self.view.addSubview(sv)
    let marg = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    let safe = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:safe.topAnchor, constant: 200),
        sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:marg.leadingAnchor,constant: 100), sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:marg.trailingAnchor,constant: -100), //sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:safe.bottomAnchor, constant: -200),
    ])
}
```

[image]

I tried to change this isBaselineRelativeArrangement to false and to true, but nothing does seems to change. Maybe I misinterpreted something?

Update: @matt commented below: "Your stack view is not tall enough for the distinction to matter; the label spacing is zero."
i tried to add views and substitute UITextView with UILabel to make linespacing more than 0.
Here is the code:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let saveButton = UIView()
    saveButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    saveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let saveButtonTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
    saveButtonTextView.text = "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  "
    saveButtonTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    saveButton.addSubview(saveButtonTextView)
    
    
    let revertButton = UIView()
    revertButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    revertButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let revertButtonTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
    revertButtonTextView.text = "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. "
    revertButtonTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    revertButton.addSubview(revertButtonTextView)
    
    let cancelButton = UIView()
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cancelButtonRevertView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
    cancelButtonRevertView.text = "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    cancelButtonRevertView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cancelButton.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView)
    
    
    let cancelButton1 = UIView()
    cancelButton1.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    cancelButton1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   let cancelButtonRevertView1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
         
           let textForLabe1 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic types"
           
           let paragraphStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
           //line height size
           paragraphStyle1.lineSpacing = 7
           let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textForLabe1)
           attrString1.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle1, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString1.length))
           attrString1.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString1.length))
           cancelButtonRevertView1.numberOfLines = 0
           
           cancelButtonRevertView1.attributedText = attrString1
           
    
    cancelButtonRevertView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cancelButton1.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView1)
    
    let cancelButton2 = UIView()
           cancelButton2.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
           cancelButton2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let cancelButtonRevertView2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
                
                  let textForLabel2 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic types"
                  
                  let paragraphStyle2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                  //line height size
                  paragraphStyle2.lineSpacing = 7
                  let attrString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textForLabel2)
                  attrString2.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle2, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString2.length))
                  attrString2.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString2.length))
                  cancelButtonRevertView2.numberOfLines = 0
                  
                  cancelButtonRevertView2.attributedText = attrString2
                  
           cancelButtonRevertView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
           cancelButton2.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView2)
    
    let cancelButton3 = UIView()
    cancelButton3.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    cancelButton3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cancelButtonRevertView3 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(30, 0, 100, 130))
  
    let textForLabel = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic types"
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    //line height size
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 7
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textForLabel)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    cancelButtonRevertView3.numberOfLines = 0
    
    cancelButtonRevertView3.attributedText = attrString
    
    
    cancelButtonRevertView3.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cancelButton3.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView3)
    
    let views = [saveButton,revertButton,cancelButton3,cancelButton,cancelButton1,cancelButton2]
    
    saveButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    revertButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    cancelButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    cancelButton1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    cancelButton2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
     cancelButton3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    // give the stack view arranged subviews
    let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: views)
    // configure the stack view
    sv.axis = .vertical
    //sv.alignment = .fill
    sv.distribution = .equalSpacing
    // constrain the stack view
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.isBaselineRelativeArrangement = true
    self.view.addSubview(sv)
    let marg = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    let safe = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:safe.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:marg.leadingAnchor,constant: 0), sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:marg.trailingAnchor,constant: 0)
        //, //sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:safe.bottomAnchor, constant: -200),
    ])
}
```

[image]

I switched this property again, but no change to seemed to manifest :(

UPDATE: @matt commented below: You're still not doing any actual spacing so there is no "vertical space between views" to talk about. Do you see?

Well, I adapted my code so there will be vertical space between subviews of stackView.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    [![enter image description here][3]][3] super.viewDidLoad()
    let saveButton = UIView()
    saveButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    saveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let saveButtonTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
    saveButtonTextView.text = "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  "
    saveButtonTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    saveButton.addSubview(saveButtonTextView)
    
    
    let revertButton = UIView()
    revertButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    revertButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let revertButtonTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
    revertButtonTextView.text = "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. "
    revertButtonTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    revertButton.addSubview(revertButtonTextView)
    
    let cancelButton = UIView()
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cancelButtonRevertView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
    cancelButtonRevertView.text = "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    cancelButtonRevertView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cancelButton.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView)
    
    
    let cancelButton1 = UIView()
    cancelButton1.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    cancelButton1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   let cancelButtonRevertView1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
         
           let textForLabe1 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic types"
           
           let paragraphStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
           //line height size
           paragraphStyle1.lineSpacing = 7
           let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textForLabe1)
           attrString1.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle1, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString1.length))
           attrString1.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString1.length))
           cancelButtonRevertView1.numberOfLines = 0
           
           cancelButtonRevertView1.attributedText = attrString1
           
    
    cancelButtonRevertView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cancelButton1.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView1)
    
    let cancelButton2 = UIView()
           cancelButton2.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
           cancelButton2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let cancelButtonRevertView2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 130))
                
                  let textForLabel2 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic types"
                  
                  let paragraphStyle2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                  //line height size
                  paragraphStyle2.lineSpacing = 7
                  let attrString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textForLabel2)
                  attrString2.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle2, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString2.length))
                  attrString2.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString2.length))
                  cancelButtonRevertView2.numberOfLines = 0
                  
                  cancelButtonRevertView2.attributedText = attrString2
                  
           cancelButtonRevertView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
           cancelButton2.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView2)
    
    let cancelButton3 = UIView()
    cancelButton3.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    cancelButton3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cancelButtonRevertView3 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(30, 0, 100, 130))
  
    let textForLabel = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic types"
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    //line height size
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 7
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textForLabel)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    cancelButtonRevertView3.numberOfLines = 0
    
    cancelButtonRevertView3.attributedText = attrString
    
    
    cancelButtonRevertView3.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cancelButton3.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView3)
    
    let views = [ saveButton, cancelButton3,cancelButton,cancelButton1,cancelButton2]
    
    saveButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    cancelButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    cancelButton1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    cancelButton2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
     cancelButton3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    // give the stack view arranged subviews
    let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: views)
    // configure the stack view
    sv.axis = .vertical
    //sv.alignment = .fill
    sv.distribution = .equalSpacing
    // constrain the stack view
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //sv.isBaselineRelativeArrangement = true
    self.view.addSubview(sv)
    let marg = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    let safe = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:safe.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:marg.leadingAnchor,constant: 0), sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:marg.trailingAnchor,constant: 0),
        sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:safe.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
    ])
```

[image]

But still... no change when I toggle this property from false to true. I really think I don't understand some crucial idea, but I don't know what this idea about. ((

Comment: Your stack view is not tall enough for the distinction to matter; the label spacing is zero.

Comment: @matt i tried to recreate your conditions in code, so updated my question with results, please, could you look at it one more time?

Comment: You're still not doing any actual _spacing_ so there is no "vertical space between views" to talk about. Do you see?

Comment: @matt thank for looking at the question I changed the code again to meet this requirement and updated the question and posted screenshot of the results, please look at the question  how can I change the code to really meet the requirement? actually I am reading your book iOS 13 dive deep in view, view controllers... and stumbled upon on this property on p.58 you wrote: "If the axis is .vertical, you can still involve the subviews’ baselines in their spacing by setting the stack view’s isBaselineRelativeArrangement to true." but that words seemed to me vague(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that shows the difference:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.alignment = .fill
    stack.distribution = .fill
    stack.isBaselineRelativeArrangement = false
    self.view.addSubview(stack)
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    let s = "thank for looking at the question I changed the code again to meet this requirement and updated the question and posted screenshot of the results, please look at the question thank for looking at the question I changed the code again to meet this requirement and updated the question and posted screenshot of the results, please look at the question"
    let lab1 = UILabel()
    lab1.numberOfLines = 0
    lab1.text = s
    stack.addArrangedSubview(lab1)
    lab1.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(100), for: .vertical)
    
    let lab2 = UILabel()
    lab2.numberOfLines = 0
    lab2.text = "testing\ntesting\ntesting\ntesting\ntesting"
    stack.addArrangedSubview(lab2)
    
    let lab3 = UILabel()
    lab3.numberOfLines = 0
    lab3.text = s
    stack.addArrangedSubview(lab3)
    
    // comment this out for an even more dramatic effect
    stack.setCustomSpacing(30, after: lab2)

}
```

Try that with different values for `stack.isBaselineRelativeArrangement`. You will see that the space between the second and third labels is measured differently.

Comment: Actually it's even more dramatic if you comment out `stack.setCustomSpacing(30, after: lab2)`. In that case, when we align by the first baseline, the second label crashes into the third, because you've now said that its last baseline should be in the same position vertically as the first baseline of the third label.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some "beating" my head upon this question I think I found one of many changes that shows this  isBaselineRelativeArrangement property in UIStackView alignment process.

Now, I tried not to set alignment property, instead I set directly spacing property.

```
    let saveButton = UIView()
    saveButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    saveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let saveButtonTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 10, 100, 130))
    saveButtonTextView.text = "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  "
    saveButtonTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    saveButton.addSubview(saveButtonTextView)
    
    
    let revertButton = UIView()
    revertButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    revertButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let revertButtonTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(15, 10, 100, 130))
    revertButtonTextView.text = "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. "
    revertButtonTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    revertButton.addSubview(revertButtonTextView)
    
    let cancelButton = UIView()
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cancelButtonRevertView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(0, 20, 100, 130))
    cancelButtonRevertView.text = "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    cancelButtonRevertView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cancelButton.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView)
    
    
    let cancelButton1 = UIView()
    cancelButton1.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    cancelButton1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cancelButtonRevertView1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(20, 20, 100, 130))
    
    let textForLabe1 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic types"
    
    let paragraphStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    //line height size
    paragraphStyle1.lineSpacing = 7
    let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textForLabe1)
    attrString1.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle1, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString1.length))
    attrString1.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString1.length))
    cancelButtonRevertView1.numberOfLines = 0
    
    cancelButtonRevertView1.attributedText = attrString1
    
    
    cancelButtonRevertView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cancelButton1.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView1)
    
    let cancelButton2 = UIView()
    cancelButton2.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    cancelButton2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cancelButtonRevertView2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(60, 20, 100, 130))
    
    let textForLabel2 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic types"
    
    let paragraphStyle2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    //line height size
    paragraphStyle2.lineSpacing = 7
    let attrString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textForLabel2)
    attrString2.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle2, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString2.length))
    attrString2.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString2.length))
    cancelButtonRevertView2.numberOfLines = 0
    
    cancelButtonRevertView2.attributedText = attrString2
    
    cancelButtonRevertView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    cancelButton2.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView2)
    
    let cancelButton3 = UIView()
    cancelButton3.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    cancelButton3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let cancelButtonRevertView3 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(600, 20, 200, 130))
    
    let textForLabel = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic types"
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    //line height size
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 7
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textForLabel)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    cancelButtonRevertView3.numberOfLines = 0
    
    cancelButtonRevertView3.attributedText = attrString
    
    
    cancelButtonRevertView3.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    cancelButton3.addSubview(cancelButtonRevertView3)
    
    let views = [saveButton,cancelButtonRevertView1, cancelButtonRevertView2, cancelButtonRevertView3]
 
    let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: views)
    sv.axis = .vertical
    sv.spacing = 58.0
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.isBaselineRelativeArrangement = false
    
    self.view.addSubview(sv)
    let marg = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    let safe = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:safe.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:marg.leadingAnchor,constant: 0), sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:marg.trailingAnchor,constant: 0),
        sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:safe.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
    ])
```

[image]

Then! A changed the sv.isBaselineRelativeArrangement to equal to true. And this property really began to manifest changes in stackView layout!

[image]

Awesome. But I can be wrong.